# How to render a form and table on same page

Tags: forms, drupal

Can someone help me render a form and table on the same page? I'm sure it's easy, but can't think of how to do it.

Here's hook_menu:

```
 function ncbi_subsites_menu() {
        $items = array();

        $items['admin/content/ncbi_subsites'] = array(
            'title' => 'NCBI Subsites Module',
            'description' => 'Informs Drupal about NCBI subsites as defined by the Content Inventory database',
            'page callback' => 'ncbi_subsites_show_main_page',
            'access arguments' => array( 'administer site configuration' ),
            'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        );
        return $items;
}
```

Here's the callback:

```
function ncbi_subsites_show_main_page() {
    $subsites = ncbi_subsites_get_subsites_from_inventory(); // fnc returns associative array from inventory, defined in include
    return ncbi_subsites_make_table( $subsites );
}
```

In the callback I call some helper functions that return a themed, paged table.

What I want is a small form above the table. How would I that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a long time ago, but perhaps someone could use an general updated answer. The clearest way to do this is to have three functions: one for the page callback, one for the form, and one for the table.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  //form fields
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Function for table.
 */
function my_module_table() {
  //Define $header
  //Define $rows
  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));
}

/**
 * Page callback function for /my_module as defined in hook_menu().
 */
function _my_module() {
  $page = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_module_form'));
  $page .= my_module_table();
  return $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ncbi_subsites_show_main_page() {  
    $subsites = ncbi_subsites_get_subsites_from_inventory(); 
    $page = drupal_get_form('your_form');  
    $page .= ncbi_subsites_make_table( $subsites );  
    return $page;  
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

This is a full working example to show a form and a table in the same page:

```
<?php


/*
* Implements hook_mennu()
*/
function test_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title'             => t('Test'),
    'page callback'     => 'test_search_page',
    'access callback'   => True,
  );

  return $items;
}


function test_search_page(){
    $form = drupal_get_form('test_search_form');

    return $form;
}


function test_search_form($form, &$form_state){
  $header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));
  $rows = Null;
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'textfield',
    '#title'            => t('Name'),
    '#required'         => True,
    '#default_value'    => isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : Null
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'           => 'submit',
    '#value'          => t('submit'),
  );



  if (isset($_GET['name'])){
    $rows = get_data();
  }
  $form['table'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#empty' => t('Aucun résultat.')
  );
  $form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));

  /*
  if (isset($form_state['table'])) {
    $form['table']  = $form_state['table'];
  }
  $form['pager'] = array('#markup' => theme('pager'));
  */
  return $form;
}

function test_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
   $form_state['redirect'] = array(
    // $path
    'test',
    // $options
    array('query' => array('name' => $form_state['values']['name'])),
    // $http_response_code
    302,
  );
}

//$header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));

function get_data(){
    $data =  array(
        0   => array(
            'id' => '0',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        1   => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        2   => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        3   => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        4   => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        5   => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        6   => array(
            'id' => '6',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        7   => array(
            'id' => '7',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        8   => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        9   => array(
            'id' => '9',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        10   => array(
            'id' => '10',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        ),
        11   => array(
            'id' => '11',
            'name'  => 'pokpokpok',
            'firstname' => 'pokpokpok',
        )
    );
    $paging = pager_array_splice($data, 2);

    return $paging;
}
/*
    $header = array(t('id'), t('name'), t('firstname'));

    $form_state['table'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#rows' => $paging,
      '#empty' => t('Aucun r?sultat.')
    );

    $form_state['rebuild'] = True;*/


function pager_array_splice($data, $limit = 9, $element = 0) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total, $pager_total_items;
  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

  // Convert comma-separated $page to an array, used by other functions.
  $pager_page_array = explode(',', $page);

  // We calculate the total of pages as ceil(items / limit).
  $pager_total_items[$element] = count($data);
  $pager_total[$element] = ceil($pager_total_items[$element] / $limit);
  $pager_page_array[$element] = max(0, min((int)$pager_page_array[$element], ((int)$pager_total[$element]) - 1));
  return array_slice($data, $pager_page_array[$element] * $limit, $limit, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Please document the code to ensure it can be understood. Perhaps you could remove the commented out code also.